# Can javascript be used in static FBML under pages' tab?

Tags: facebook

I want to hover the image in static FBML page.

But even the following simple code doesn't work:

```
<div id="button1">button1</div>
<div id="button2" onmouseover="document.getElementById('button1').setStyle({display: 'none'})">button2</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('button1').setStyle({display: 'none'});
</script>
```

When "onmouseover" changes to "onclick", it works.

```
<div id="button1">button1</div>
<div id="button2" onclick="document.getElementById('button1').setStyle({display: 'none'})">button2</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('button1').setStyle({display: 'none'});
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is not allowed in facebook FBML applications (they may be allowed in IFrame applications but im not certain). See http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS for the alternative, Facebook JS.

EDIT:
In this case it will not work as javascript placed in profile boxes is not executed until the first user event. From the FBJS wiki:

"In profile boxes, inline scripts are deferred until the first "active" event is triggered by a user. An active event is considered either onfocus, onclick, onmousedown, and so forth. Basically anything that requires a mouse click is an "active" event. On a canvas page, however, this example works just fine."

Comment: the wiki page mentions that code should be setup like this:

<script>
<!--
//-->
</script>

try inserting your FBJS within these script tags like so:

<script>
<!--
document.getElementById('button1').setStyle({display: 'none'});
//-->
</script>

Comment: please note there should be line breaks after each comment and the script tags - see http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS#The_Basics and look at the "best practice" part

Comment: is this for a profile box? if so, the wiki mentions that javascript will only be executed after the user executes an event such as onclick.

Comment: "In profile boxes, inline scripts are deferred until the first "active" event is triggered by a user. An active event is considered either onfocus, onclick, onmousedown, and so forth. Basically anything that requires a mouse click is an "active" event. On a canvas page, however, this example works just fine."

under "The Basics" section of the wiki