# facebook ignore javascript events

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I have a fbml app with a contact form and inputs like this one:

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" value="Name" name="name" id="name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name';" /><br />
```

Does anybody know why facebook ignore this javascript:

```
onfocus="if(this.value=='Name')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name';"
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can javascript be used in static FBML under pages' tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866731/can-javascript-be-used-in-static-fbml-under-pages-tab)

Answer (score 0):

FBML apps don't support pure javascript, instead you have to use facebook's own js implementation called [FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS).

Your FBJS should look something like this (not tested):

```
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('focus', function(e){ 
    if(document.getElementById('name').getValue() == 'Name') {
        document.getElementById('name').setValue('');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Jamland is focus event getting triggered? Do you see any errors?